# For random vectors $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_m)^T \in R^m$ and $Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)^T \in R^n$

Tags: self-study, expected-value, matrix, covariance-matrix, conditional-expectation

Here is an exercise on linear transformations of random vectors. I don't understand why we have to have a condition on $X$. If anyone can help me with these properties, that would be great.

For random vectors $X$ = ($X_1$, . . . , $X_m$$)^T$∈ $R^m$ and $Y$ = ($Y_1$, . . . , $Y_n$$)^T$∈ $R^n$. Suppose that E[$Y$|$X$=$x$] = $a$ +$B$$x$ is a linear function of $x$ ($a$ ∈ $R_n$ and $B$ is n × m).

(a) Show that $µ_Y$ = $a$ + $B$$µ_X$. (Condition on $X$).

(b) Show that E[$Y$$X^T$] = $a$$µ^T$$_X$ +$B$E[$X$$X^T$], and so show that Cov($Y$, $X$) = $B$Var($X$). (Condition on $X$ again).

What I tried getting for part a):

$µ_Y$ = E[$Y$] = E[E[$Y$|$X$=$x$]] = E[$a$ +$B$$x$] (by law of total expectation) = $a$ +$B$$E[X]$ = $a$ + $B$$µ_X$

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Are you asking for help with showing (a) and (b), or just with help understanding why we have to condition on X?

Comment: What approach have you taken with this problem and where are you stuck.

Comment: @MichaelOberst my main concern, is how I can get $µ_Y$ from $µ_X$, just by having a condition of X = x.

Comment: I have updated what I have attempted to do for part (a) @Chaconne

Comment: I have updated what I have attempted to do for part (a) @MichaelChernick

Comment: $\text{E}Y \neq \text{E}Y|X=x$, at least not in general.  It does, however, equal $\text{E}_x[\text{E}Y|X=x]$, which will help.  $\text{E}_x$ means "expectation with respect to $x$".